# How can integrate gradle project wih Eclipse (maven) based instrumentation tests

Tags: maven, android-studio, android-instrumentation

I have an android project in AndroidStudio, but we must outsource the Instrumentation test to Eclipse (simple Java projet which builded by maven). I don't would like to tell the whole development and QA story about why, I'm just kindly asking can anyone tell me, who can I integrate an maven independed instrumentation test project with my Android Studio based project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In gradle you can make a .jar from your project by building it, and then you can publish the .jar artifact to any maven repo (check [this](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_management.html) if your are not familiar with artifact publishing).
Something like this:

```
artifacts {
    archives file("path/to/your/project_output.jar")
}
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "file://${System.env.HOME}/.m2/repository/")
            pom.groupId = 'com.yourcompany'
            pom.artifactId = 'yourartifactid'
            pom.version = '0.1.0'
        }
    }
}
```

This will publish your project's compiled jar files to your local maven repository.
Look for the .jar file in the build/intermediates/... folder (classes.jar its default name I think)
Also, you should publish your .apk file too if your test project needs it.